# Scala console wont run

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu-16.04

The scala console wont run even though I have set java 8 as default version. Below is the error I am getting :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/script/Compilable
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.createInterpreter(ILoop.scala:118)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:911)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:74)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

And these are the java versions installed:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing/usr/bin/java).

Selection   Path                                 Priority  Status
```

---

```
 0         /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java       1091  auto mode
 1         /usr/bin/gij-4.8                          1048  manual mode
*2         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081  manual mode
 3         /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java       1091  manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Thankyou.

Comment: What did you run at the command line to get this?

Comment: Check the Java version that is used by scala when you start in terminal.          $ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_172).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

Comment: Andy are you asking to check for the java versions?

Comment: Mansoor can tell me the exact command to check the java version my scala or sbt is using?Thankyou.

Comment: Okay I checked my sbt does uses java_version = '8'.

Comment: Are you running with the command `scala` or `sbt console`? If it's `scala`, the version set in build.sbt doesn't matter.

Comment: @gunjanpatait it might help if you edited your question to show precisely what commands you are running.